# Symfony-docker build throws class not found error

Tags: php, docker, symfony

This is a link to the full repository, in case you need all the files:
https://github.com/tech0tron/civstock-symfony

When I run `docker-compose build --pull --no-cache`, it runs all the way to step 36 until it gives this error:

```
+ composer run-script post-install-cmd

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle" not found in /srv/app/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php:131
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 /srv/app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(382): App\Kernel->registerBundles()
!!  #1 /srv/app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(766): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
!!  #2 /srv/app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(128): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->preBoot()
!!  #3 /srv/app/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(166): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
!!  #4 /srv/app/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(72): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands()
!!  #5 /srv/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun()
!!  #6 /srv/app/vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/ConsoleApplicationRunner.php(54): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
!!  #7 /srv/app/vendor/autoload_runtime.php(29): Symfony\Component\Runtime\Runner\Symfony\ConsoleApplicationRunner->run()
!!  #8 /srv/app/bin/console(11): require_once('...')
!!  #9 {main}
!!    thrown in /srv/app/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php on line 131
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
The command '/bin/sh -c set -eux;   mkdir -p var/cache var/log;     composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-progress --no-scripts --no-interaction;    composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev;   composer symfony:dump-env prod;     composer run-script post-install-cmd;   chmod +x bin/console; sync' returned a non-zero code: 255
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build : Build failed
```

My bundles.php file supposedly shows the TwigBundle class being registered:

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

What should I change to correct this?

Comment: Can we see your composer.json ?

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the repository you provided. You are missing `symfony/twig-bundle` from your dependency list, and so it is not installed.

The reason it stops at step 36 is when you run `composer symfony:dump-env prod` you receive an error from Symfony when it tries to process your bundles.php and cannot lot the bundle.

You will need to require the correct bundle, and try again.

`composer require symfony/twig-bundle`